# startActivity and intercept intent extras

Tags: java, android, security

I'm considering to do the following for log in a user:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this,DoLoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("login",mLogin);
intent.putExtra("password",mPassword);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is that secure, or other apps can easily listen/read the intent parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current approach is secure, no other app can listen or read these values.

You are using [Explicit intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ires) `[you actually specify the activity that is required to respond to the intent]` and that is listen by only that class which is declared in Intent. So this is Secure.

Answer (score 1):

For your information you can pass object through intent, this will help in the scenario of passing bunch of values. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

For security enhancement, passwords should be stored in char arrays (char[]) and then cleared after usage by clearing the array like that:

```
Arrays.fill(password, (char) 0);
```